# Login without password FOSUserBundle Symfony3

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, fosuserbundle

I want to authorize a user without using a password. Authorization will only take place on the field username. Is it possible to do this in `FOSUserBundle`? I know that you can write a custom `UserProvider`, but my goal is to do it with `FOSUserBundle`!

Comment: The FOSUserBundle does not do authentication nor can you authenticate via a user provider.  google for "symfony fosuserbundle custom authenticator" and read enough until you understand this.  What you need to do is to plug in your own guard authenticator.

Answer (score 0):

In login form, make the password field hidden (instead of type="password"), with a value of "whatever" (which will be the password of all the users).

Try if it is possible?

Comment: This seems like an odd and not recommended way to authenticate someone. If a password is needed then the field should be shown and a valid user password entered, otherwise the form shouldn't have a password field at all and the Authenticator will handle authenticating the user without a password